# Screen flicker on mouse over using Blender on Mac Studio

Tags: interface, osx, hardware

There is a curious flicker to the screen happening when we mouse over the windows of some software using our Mac Studio. For example, the Blender window will go slightly darker when mousing over it, then go back to normal when the mouse pointer is not on the software window.

Mainly Adobe Lightroom and Blender at this point are affected in our workflow, however there could be others. Both software support M1 processors.

[image]

For Adobe, we researched and found that the hardware acceleration caused the issue. [Turning that off solved the issue](https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/picture-becomes-brighter-when-mouse-hovers/td-p/11394889), but at the cost of no acceleration.

Apparently, Adobe has not fixed the issue with acceleration on.

However, when using Blender, we have no such luck finding a solution. Turning off hardware acceleration still shows the flicker issue on mouse over. Oddly, the glitch won't show up right away, we'll complete a render or do a preview and then the flicker will appear on mouse over. We are using the most up to date version of the software available as well.